# Javascript Unit Testing - DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I'm quite new to Javacript Unit testing. One thing keep bothering me. When testing javascript, we often need to do the DOM manipulation. It looks like I am unit testing a method/function in a Controller/Component, but I still need to depend on the HTML elements in my templates. Once the id(or attributes used to be selectors in my test cases) is changed, my test cases also need to be CHANGED! Wouldn't this violate the purpose of unit testing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the toughest parts of javascript unit testing is not the testing, it's learning how to architect your code so that it is testable.

You need to structure your code with a clear separation of testable logic and DOM manipulation.

My rule of thumb is this:

If you are testing anything that is dependent on the DOM structure, then you are doing it wrong.

In summary:Try to test data manipulations and logical operations only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But where should we test the parts with DOM Manipulation? End-to-end testing? And do you have any recommended books/tutorials talking about this topic?

Comment: I assume you are using something like jQuery. In which case let jquery test DOM manipulation and focus on abstracting the testable logic out of your DOM updates. Structure your code in such a way that you manipulate the DOM based on the results of testable code. A good resource for javascript testing is http://www.elijahmanor.com/

He is easily on of my favorite and most respected bloggers in the industry.

Comment: I respectfully disagree @BentOnCoding. DOM manipulation is a critical part of the web User Experience. If we can't test that, then we aren't good at what we do. DOM testing has been disregarded because there doesn't seem to be a good way to test it. But I'm finding more and more that libraries are failing (such as Handlebarsjs) because the DOM can't be acurately tested for manipulation.

Comment: I'd say your dom maninulation is always determined by testable business logic. If there are problems with your dom manipluation, it's due to poorly architected/tested code. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @BentOnCoding Suppose a web application replaces all `<input class='myFancyDateBox'>` with a complex date picker. Then, if we don't verify that we are indeed selecting the correct elements, the behavior of the replacing elements seems irrelevant.

Comment: I'm resurrecting this from the past. Is there an answer for a scenario like @Cuadue mentioned? What can be done to make sure the UI is acting the way it should be, i.e. elements being hidden/shown/changed? Some sort of Selenium-like automation craziness?

Comment: Selenium can be a robust solution to Web UI testing.

Comment: @BentOnCoding that's not always the case. Is not that you depend on a DOM structure, but that you make sure the templates are consuming your component logic correctly.
I can make an app have 100% coverage, 1000's of tests and yet make it completely useless if I don't have the right markup to call the component's logic. There's always pros and cons in every approach. That's the actual rule of thumb to consider.

Comment: I'm wondering how the DOM Testing Library comes into play in this discussion. The intent of that library is to simulate how a user would interact with your application. It provides queries like `getByText`, `getByLabelText`, `getByRole`, etc., which help alleviate the problem of directly depending on elements' attributes, like class or id. That way, your tests are less coupled to the implementation of your app.

Answer (score 4):

I think I'd second @BentOnCoding's recommendation that what you want to unit test is *your code*, not anything else. When it comes to DOM manipulation, that's browser code, such as appendChild, replaceChild etc. If you're using jQuery or some other library, the same still applies--you're calling some other code to do the manipulation, and you don't need to test that.
So how do you assert that calling some function on your viewmodel/controller resulted in the DOM structure that you wanted? You don't. Just as you wouldn't unit test that calling a stored procedure on a DB resulted in a specific row in a specific table. You need to instead think about how to abstract out the parts of your controller that deal with inputs/outputs from the parts that manipulate the DOM.
For instance, if you had a method that called alert() based on some conditions, you'd want to separate the method into two:

- One that takes and processes the inputs
- One that calls window.alert()

During the test, you'd substitute window.alert (or your proxy method to it) with a fake (see SinonJS), and call your input processor with the conditions to cause (or not cause) the alert. You can then assert different values on whether the fake was called, how many times, with what values, etc. You don't actually test window.alert() because it's external to your code. It's *assumed* that those external dependencies work correctly. If they don't, then that's a bug for that library, but it's not your unit test's job to uncover those bugs. You're only interested in verifying *your own code*.

Answer (score 4):

I respectfully disagree with @BentOnCoding. Most often a component is more than just its class. Component combines an HTML template and a JavaScript/TypeScript class. That's why you should test that the template and the class work together as intended. The class-only tests can tell you about class behavior. But they cannot tell you if the component is going to render properly and respond to user input.

Some people say you should test it in integration tests. But integration tests are slower to write/run and more expensive (in terms of time and resources) to run/maintain. So, testing most of your component functionality in integration tests might slow you down.

It doesn't mean you should skip integration tests. While integration and E2E tests may be slower and expensive than unit tests, they bring you more confidence that your app is working as intended. Integration test is where individual units/components are combined and tested as a group. It shouldn't be considered as an only place to test your component's template.

Comment: Unit vs e2e/integration tests: "Whatever CAN be tested at unit test level, SHOULD be tested at unit test level"

Comment: Indeed, that's better. Though it depends on your team or app size.
Moving most of the testing to integration/functional level will slow everything down.
A multirepo approach can help with that, or some clever setup on a monorepo.